Acumatica Convert Quote To Project and Generate new TaskID
When converting Project Quote to Projects I would like to generate New Task ID : for example AFR-AFFR-NEW in Project Quotes (PM304500) should become AFR-AFFR-00281 in Projects screen (PM301000). '00281' comes from Numbering Sequence

It doesn't work with this code:
 protected void PMTask_RowInserted(PXCache cache, PXRowInsertedEventArgs e)
       {
  var row = (PMTask)e.Row;
  // Acuminator disable once PX1045 PXGraphCreateInstanceInEventHandlers [Justification]
          ProjectEntry project = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ProjectEntry>();
     

      PMQuoteMaint graph=PXGraph.CreateInstance<PMQuoteMaint>();
                NumberingMaint graphSequenceNum = PXGraph.CreateInstance<NumberingMaint>();
            string seq = "PHASE";
            NumberingSequence querynumdoss = SelectFrom<NumberingSequence>.Where<NumberingSequence.numberingID.IsEqual<@P.AsString>>.View.SelectWindowed(Base, 0, 1, seq);
            string maxdoss = querynumdoss.LastNbr;
            int maxdossint = Int32.Parse(maxdoss);
          string statut = "D";
PXTrace.WriteInformation(maxdoss);
PXTrace.WriteInformation(maxdossint.ToString());
foreach (PMTask task in Base.Tasks.Select())
                
            {
                string phs = task.TaskCD;
                string phspart1 = task.TaskCD.Substring(0, 7);
                 maxdossint = maxdossint + 1;
                string phspart2 = maxdossint.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
                string taskcode = phspart1 + phspart2;
                 PXTrace.WriteInformation(taskcode);
             Base.Caches[typeof(PMTask)].SetValueExt<PMTask.status>(row, statut);
               Base.Caches[typeof(PMTask)].SetValueExt<PMTask.taskCD>(row, taskcode);
               
            }

          
        }



The invalid status exception is thrown in RowPersiting event handler of PMTask DAC in the ProjectEntry graph:
void _(Events.RowPersisting<PMTask> e)
{
    if (e.Operation != PXDBOperation.Delete && 
        e.Row.Status == ProjectTaskStatus.Active && 
        e.Row.IsActive != true)
    {
        throw new PXException(Messages.TaskCannotBeSaved, e.Row.TaskCD);
    }
}

A good place to start troubleshooting is inspecting the content of graph variables Caches[typeof(PMTask)].Cached to make sure it doesn't contain tasks objects with active status.
You are creating new graphs but are not using them:
ProjectEntry project = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ProjectEntry>();
PMQuoteMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<PMQuoteMaint>();

It's not clear which graph is used in your example because class declaration is missing. Maybe your event handler is inside a PMQuoteMaint graph extension and the graph is Base. If that's the case you can declare event handler with InstanceCreated method to check status.
public PXAction<PMQuote> convertToProject;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Convert to Project", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
[PXButton]
public IEnumerable ConvertToProject(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<ProjectEntry>((graph) =>
    {
        graph.RowPersisting.AddHandler<PMTask>((cache, e) =>
        {
            // Check Task Status
        }
    });

    IEnumerable<PMQuote> quotes = Base.ConvertToProject(adapter);

    return quotes;
}

Note that interfering with the numbering sequence generation might lead to unexpected consequences. There are validations that checks previous and next number in the sequence.
